# How can I use extension library of three.js (such as OBJLoader, SceneUtils...) in angular 6?

Tags: angular, three.js, angular6

I try to use following code, but it does not work.

```
npm i --save three-obj-loader

import * as tol from 'three-obj-loader';
const OBJLoader = tol(THREE);

let loader = new OBJLoader():
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug in the [`three-obj-loader`](https://github.com/sohamkamani/three-object-loader) package, it doesn't seem to have been updated in a while and may not work with more recent versions of three.js. You can file a bug there, but in general it's currently best to copy loaders from the `examples/js/loaders/*` folder of the three.js version you're using, even though that can be inconvenient. You may find some other options, for specific build systems, in this long thread: [Transform examples/js to support modules](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9562).